# How do I replace blank spaces with null values and query where values are not null? (I'm filling in a table)

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables:

table1:

| USER_NUM | FIRST_NAME | LAST_NAME |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A123 | Billy | Bob |
| A124 | Billy | Joe |
|  | Jane | Doe |
|  | John | Doe |

I am trying to insert `FIRST_NAME` and `LAST_NAME` under `USER_NAME` into table2:

| OWNER_ID | USER_NUM | USER_NAME |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | A123 |  |
| 112 | A124 |  |

Using this query:

```
BEGIN
  FOR c1 IN (SELECT UPPER(t1.USER_NUM) number
                    ,t1.FIRST_NAME || ' ' || LAST_NAME user_name
               FROM table1 t1
              INNER JOIN table2 t2
                 ON number = t2.USER_NUM
              WHERE regexp_replace(number, '[[:space:]]+', NULL) IS NOT NULL
             )
  LOOP
    INSERT INTO table2 (USER_NAME) values (c1.user_name)
  END LOOP;
END;
```

The problem is, if I isolate my select statement I still get blank values for `USER_NUM` with a table looking like this:

| USER_NUM | USER_NAME |
| --- | --- |
| A123 | Billy Bob |
| A124 | Billy Joe |
|  | Jane Doe |
|  | John Doe |

and I get an error saying I can't insert null values into my table.

How do I get rid of these blank values in `USER_NUM`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want `update`:

```
update table2 t2
    set user_name = (select t1.FIRST_NAME || ' ' || t1.LAST_NAME
                     from table1 t1
                     where t1.user_num = t2.user_num
                    )
    where exists (select 1
                  from table1 t1
                  where t1.user_num = t2.user_num
                 );
```